# Layer sets not enabled after change style via REST.

Tags: geoserver, rest

I changing layer's style via REST api:

```
curl.exe -v -u new_user:123456 -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/xml" 
-d "<layer><defaultStyle><name>poi</name></defaultStyle></layer>" 
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/cite:point
```

Style changing, but in layer's Publishing tab i see that layer sets not enabled.

[image]

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force the layer to be enabled by adding an **enabled-element** with a value of **true** to the **layer-element**. So your cURL PUT-request should look like this:

```
curl.exe -v -u new_user:123456 -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/xml" 
-d "<layer><defaultStyle><name>poi</name></defaultStyle><enabled>true</enabled></layer>" 
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/cite:point
```

Comment: Yeah your code it's only way for now. I get same answer in geoserver mail list.

Comment: The same happened for me when updating the feature type and adding the enabled element helped: `<featureType><enabled>true</enabled></featureType>`. Thanks.