# Changing Style of Layer in GeoServer REST API (PHP)

Tags: geoserver, php, geoserver-rest-api

I would like to change the layer's style via REST. My problem is very similar to [Layer sets not enabled after change style via REST.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75207) and [How to set default style of layer using rest api in Geoserver](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94313).

Running the following via curl works:

```
curl.exe -v -u user:password -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/xml" 
-d "<layer><defaultStyle><name>poi</name></defaultStyle></layer>" 
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/workspace:layer
```

Though, I'm building on top of [GeoServerWrapper](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-geoserver/) in PHP provided by IBM to interact with the GeoServer REST API so my code is as follows:

```
private function runApi($apiPath, $method = 'GET', $data = '', $contentType = 'text/xml') {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->serverUrl.'rest/'.$apiPath);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->username.":".$this->password); 
    if ($method == 'POST') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    } else if ($method == 'DELETE' || $method == 'PUT') {
        // return $method;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    }

    if ($data != '') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
            array("Content-Type: $contentType",
            'Content-Length: '.strlen($data))
        );
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $rslt = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

    if ($info['http_code'] == 401) {
        return 'Access denied. Check login credentials.';
    } else {
        return $rslt;
    }
}

public function addStyleToLayer($layerName, $workspaceName, $styleName) {
    return $this->runApi('layers/'.urlencode($workspaceName).':'.urlencode($layerName).'', 'PUT', '<layer><defaultStyle><name>'.htmlentities($styleName, ENT_COMPAT).'</name></defaultStyle><enabled>true</enabled></layer>');
}
```

Specifying 'PUT' didn't work so I'm back to the drawing boards.

---

I'm sending these parameters to the GeoServer REST:

```
$.ajax({
               url: 'geoserverRestFinal.php',
               type: 'PUT',
               data: {
                'action': 'assignstyle',
                'username': $('#username').val(),
                'password': $('#password').val(),
                'workspace': $('#assignstyle_workspace').val(),
                'layer': $('#assignstyle_layer').val(),
                'stylename': $('#assignstyle_stylename').val()
               },
               success: function(ret) {
                $('#assignstyle_results').html(escape(ret).replace(/%(..)/g,"&#x$1;")); 
               }
            });
```

From the 'action' parameter:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
include "GeoserverWrapper.php";
$geoserver = new GeoserverWrapper('http://server:8080/geoserver/', $_REQUEST['username'], $_REQUEST['password']);

switch ($_REQUEST['action']) {
    case 'assignstyle':
        print_r($geoserver->addStyleToLayer($_REQUEST['layer'], $_REQUEST['workspace'], $_REQUEST['stylename']));
        break;
}

return;}
```

---

My jQuery Ajax call is sending my data as Form Data, not as Query Strs.

Current:

```
http://server/php/geoserverRestFinal.php
```

Form Data
    action:assignstyle
    username:user
    password:password
    workspace:geoportal
    layer:glocalidad
    stylename:point

Should be:

```
http://server/php/geoserverRestFinal.php?action=assignstyle&username=user&password=password&workspace=geoportal&layer=glocalidad&stylename=point
```

Looking into [jQuery.params](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)

Comment: can you show us what is actually sent to the server by your code so we can compare it to the curl example?

Comment: edit 2 has what is being sent to the server

Answer (score -1):

optional. this is function php for change exist layer style in geoserver v2.3.0.

I solved it by folowing function notice that $params it have to put "true" for enable layer after chang style in geoserver.

```
function change_layer_style($url_layer,$style_name) {
    $params = '<layer><defaultStyle><name>'.$style_name.'</name></defaultStyle><enabled>true</enabled></layer>';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_layer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,"user:password"); //geoserver.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Receive server response ...


    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);
    return $response;


}


    //--> how to use.
    //--> 1. config your geoserver url.
    $your_workspace = "xxx";
    $your_layer_name = = "bbb";

    $url_layer = "http://xxxx.co.uk:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/".$your_workspace.":".$your_layer_name;
    $style_name ="your_exist_style_name";

    //--> call above function.
    change_layer_style($url_layer,$style_name);
```